# Allow direct URL access to a specific file while directory listing is disabled in Tomcat

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

Assume I have URL www.MyWebApp.com and directory /MyDirectory. If someone calls this http://www.MyWebApp.com/MyDirectory  I know that in Tomcat, there is a setting to disable directory listing

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

So while the above part is great. I want to allow access to specific file if the user knows the exact name of file.  For example, if user knows that that directory has file MyFile.jpg and calls the following, 
   http://www.MyWebApp.com/MyDirectory/MyFile.jpg

I want them to be able to get that file. Is there a way of doing this? Any help or idea would be appreciated.

I used Tomact 7 and Apache web server.

Comment: What does not being able to list the contents of a directory have on accessing an existing file in that directory?

Comment: Hi Jon, by the way you pose your question, I assume you're saying that as it stands now, I should be able to access the "MyFile.jpg" even if listing is set to false in the tomcat web.xml file?

So going by your comment, I researched further. And you're absolutely right. It should still indeed work. My issue is not related to tomcat listings parameter. Thanks for your help.